# how can i fix a name error in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i tried working on a twitter clone and when i ran my rails console and ran User.all i got

```
irb(main):001:0> User.all
Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from (irb):1
        2: from app/models/user.rb:1:in `<main>'
        1: from app/models/user.rb:5:in `<class:User>'
NameError (undefined local variable or method `“Relationship”' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class)
Did you mean?  relation
```

this is my user.rb code

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :tweets


    has_many :followers, :class_name => “Relationship”, :foreign_key => “user_id”
    has_many :following, :class_name => “Relationship”, :foreign_key => “follower_id”
end
```

How do i fix my error please

am following the steps on https://codeburst.io/making-a-twitter-clone-in-raw-html-with-ruby-on-rails-and-a-lil-javascript-270a5e227cb2

Comment: Have you created the relationship.rb file in the models folder yet? Have you restarted your web server so it reloads the models?

Comment: You'll have change your quotation marks in `user.rb`, replace `“Relationship”` to `"Relationship"`, `“user_id”` to `"user_id"` and `“follower_id”` to `"follower_id"`.

Answer (score 4):

If you have pasted in exactly the code you are running, then there is a rather subtle problem: the type of quotation marks. The quotes used here:

```
“Relationship”
```

Are actually a different character than what Ruby expects:

```
"Relationship"
```

This problem could have occured if you pasted in the code from a tutorial. This other type of quote marks are often used on web pages.